# Tiny7 not booting of a usb 3.0 drive

Tags: windows-7

i have problem. I installed Tiny7 (A very minimalized version of windows 7) on a usb 3.0 drive.First i booted it up on a dell latitude e6420. After i switched to a dell latitude e6430. If i try to boot to it, during the windows 7 boot animation i get a BSOD (blue screen of death). the error code is
0x0000007b witch means Inaccessible Boot Device.Can i get some suggestions that would help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emt8D.jpg)

Comment: Are you installing Windows 7 to the removable drive or a system disk in the host machine?  Windows 7 was not designed to be portable.

Comment: im installing it to a removable drive. As far as i know windows 7, windows 8 and windows 10 are designed to be portable.

Comment: Windows absolutely was not designed to be portable.  There was a small window of time where Windows To Go did exist, it performed so wonderfully horribly, Microsoft discontinued it.  Now you can still create a Windows To Go installation, but it performs extremely bad, so bad you will think you traveled back in time to the PC dark ages.  I have never seen a Windows 7 Windows to Go installation.  If all you did was select your removable storage as the installation destination for Windows that isn't going to work.